# Which package service provides the repository for Bower?

Tags: javascript, php, composer-php, bower, dependency-management

Behind the dependency manager for PHP [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) works with the PHP package archive service [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). So when I want to defind Zend Framework 2 as a package, my project depends on, I use the syntax `developer/package`:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Project Name",
    "description": "Project Description",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.23",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">=2.3.2,<3.0.0",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I run `composer install` and looks in the Packagist archive for the packges, I defined as dependencies.

Now the [Bower](http://bower.io/):

I can define the dependencies in the `bower.json` and get them with `bower init` or load them directly with `bower install <package>`. In both cases the package can be defined as a [GitHub](https://github.com/) address or any URL (`http://sld.tld/file.js`), but also in form of `developer/package` (`bower install angular/angular.js`) or even just `package` (`bower install jquery`).

What is Bower's "Packagist"? Which package service provides the package repository for Bower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping between the package name and the repository holding the package content is done by the [Bower registry](https://github.com/bower/registry).
By default the Bower client will use the public Bower registry - http://bower.herokuapp.com.
To register a new package in the registry you need to use the `bower register` command as described [here](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/).

Answer (score 1):

You create the package in GitHub by going into your GitHub repo and creating a release. This release number will be the number that will show up in the bower.json file when you do `bower install --save`. Bower expects you to use semver http://semver.org/ and will interpret your release numbers appropriately.

When you do `bower register` it will look for a match in the number between the GitHub repo and your bower.json file and warn you if they do not match.